# Combine two columns with comma delimited strings into one column with joined unique

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Lets say I have a dataframe as following:

```text
| id| col 1 |col 2
| 1 | "A,B" |"A,D"
| 2 | "A,B" |"X,Y"
| 3 | "B,D" |"B,D"
```

I need an output as:

```text
| id|merged(col1 and col2)
| 1 | "A,B,D"
| 2 | "A,B,X,Y"
| 3 | "B,D"
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the columns `col1` and `col2` to get arrays, then union using `array_union` and finally `array_join` to get a string:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "A,B", "A,D"),
    (2, "A,B", "X,Y"),
    (3, "B,D", "B,D")
], ["id", "col1", "col2"])

df1 = df.select(
    "id",
    F.array_join(
        F.array_union(F.split("col1", ","), F.split("col2", ",")),
        ","
    ).alias("merged_col1_col2")
)

df1.show()
#+---+----------------+
#| id|merged_col1_col2|
#+---+----------------+
#|  1|           A,B,D|
#|  2|         A,B,X,Y|
#|  3|             B,D|
#+---+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a pandas function to handle the merging task, then use the apply function to add your function to merge the columns. Like this

```
import pandas as pd

def h(a,b):
  a = a.split(",")
  b = b.split(",")
  u = a + b
  return ','.join(sorted(list(set(u)))) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'col 1': ["A,B", "A,B", "B,D"], 'col 2': ["A,D", 
  "X,Y", "B,D"]})

df['merged'] = df.apply( lambda row: h(row['col 1'], row['col 2']), 
  axis = 1 )
df.head()
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a solution using Spark not pandas.